# Parsing JSON request - receiving error

Tags: c#, json

I am currently receiving JSON and I'm trying to then get that response broken down and into a class. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
public class Response
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public void Example()
{
    string JSONResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FetchDeskData("cases"));

    // Errors on this next line
    Response trimmedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(JSONResponse);
}
```

The data that "FetchDeskData("cases") is returning is ([this](http://pastebin.com/pm0i7eEZ)), however, on the line that errors, I receive the following error:

```
Error converting value "{"total_entries":598042,"page":1,"...(continues)
```

Should I be parsing this JSON in a different way? Is there something I should be doing prior to serialising/deserialising?

I'm pulling this data from desk.com, they have some documentation that you can find at http://dev.desk.com but it doesn't seem to be telling me that I need to filter something out before parsing it.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [Javascript Serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) ,for example: `var parser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var deserilized = parser.Deserialize<dynamic>(data);`

Comment: [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949666/deserialize-stream-to-listt-or-any-other-type) may also be useful.

Comment: @pedram `JavaScriptSerializer` is deprecated.

Comment: You should provide a sample of your JSON data.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I've updated the original question with a sample.

Comment: i think problem with properties , properties name is doesn't match check in Jsonresponse what-2 key names its return same name you have to give your response class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the following code in order to parse/read the response from the API:

```
private void TestProcess()
{
    JObject objData = JObject.Parse(FetchJSONData());

    string sName = (string)objData["customers"][1]["Name"];
    int iAge = (int)objData["customers"][1]["Age"];
}

private string FetchJSONData()
{
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://api.website.com");
    string sAPICredentials = "username" + ":" + "password";
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(sAPICredentials)));

    try
    {
        WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();

        Stream rcvStream = res.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader rdrStream = new StreamReader(rcvStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        string JSONResponse = rdrStream.ReadToEnd();

        return JSONResponse;
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        var response = we.Response as HttpWebResponse;

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        {
            // Deal with error
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simplified example and you should be populating a class with this information, however this should get you started in retrieving the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio 2013, 2015 to create your model classes from a json, I did it and I parsed the JSON fine.
To use this feature, you must have JSON/XML in your clipboard, put your cursor  inside a .cs file and then use the option **Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON AS Classes**

[image: Paste Special JSON as classes]

Look the code that was generated:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var str = @"{
          ""total_entries"": 598042,
          ""page"": 1,
          ""_links"": {
            ""self"": {
              ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/cases?page=1&per_page=50"",
              ""class"": ""page""
            },
            ""first"": {
              ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/cases?page=1&per_page=50"",
              ""class"": ""page""
            },
            ""last"": {
              ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/cases?page=11961&per_page=50"",
              ""class"": ""page""
            },
            ""previous"": null,
            ""next"": {
              ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/cases?page=2&per_page=50"",
              ""class"": ""page""
            }
          },
          ""_embedded"": {
            ""entries"": [
              {
                ""id"": 1,
                ""external_id"": null,
                ""blurb"": ""I want to personally thank you for signing up to try Desk.com! To ensure you get the most out of your trial,
                 here are some helpful tips and quick ways to get started: \\n\\n1. USE IT - You\\u2019ve got 14 days to try us out - please do so and tell us what you t"",
                ""priority"": 4,
                ""locked_until"": null,
                ""label_ids"": [

                ],
                ""active_at"": ""2015-01-21T15: 10: 48Z"",
                ""changed_at"": ""2015-01-21T15: 15: 44Z"",
                ""created_at"": ""2015-01-20T16: 24: 09Z"",
                ""updated_at"": ""2015-01-21T15: 15: 44Z"",
                ""first_opened_at"": ""2015-01-21T15: 10: 47Z"",
                ""opened_at"": ""2015-01-21T15: 10: 47Z"",
                ""first_resolved_at"": ""2015-01-21T15: 15: 44Z"",
                ""resolved_at"": ""2015-01-21T15: 15: 44Z"",
                ""status"": ""resolved"",
                ""active_notes_count"": 0,
                ""active_attachments_count"": 0,
                ""has_pending_interactions"": false,
                ""has_failed_interactions"": false,
                ""description"": null,
                ""language"": null,
                ""received_at"": ""2015-01-20T16: 24: 09Z"",
                ""type"": ""email"",
                ""labels"": [

                ],
                ""subject"": ""Getting Started with Your New Account"",
                ""route_status"": ""available"",
                ""custom_fields"": {
                  ""exclude_portal"": null,
                  ""exclude_notifications"": null,
                  ""case_type"": null,
                  ""product"": null,
                  ""severity"": null,
                  ""knowledge_status"": null,
                  ""desk_case_id"": null,
                  ""sla_status"": null,
                  ""priority"": null,
                  ""sla_violation"": null,
                  ""sla_milestone_completed"": null,
                  ""sync_to_salesforce"": null,
                  ""7616_pa2"": null,
                  ""7643_pa1"": null,
                  ""7714_pa1"": null,
                  ""7616_pa1"": null,
                  ""7643_pa2"": null,
                  ""7714_pa2"": null,
                  ""entitlement_name"": null,
                  ""escalation_level"": null,
                  ""testing"": null,
                  ""defect_number"": null,
                  ""channel"": null,
                  ""product_version"": null,
                  ""exclude_from_reporting"": null,
                  ""cw_id"": null,
                  ""desk_agent_id"": null,
                  ""desk_agent_name"": null,
                  ""solution_codes"": null,
                  ""7723_pa2"": null,
                  ""7670_pa2"": null,
                  ""7661_pa1"": null,
                  ""7634_pa2"": null,
                  ""7670_pa1"": null,
                  ""7758_pa1"": null,
                  ""7634_pa1"": null,
                  ""7688_pa1"": null,
                  ""7723_pa1"": null,
                  ""7688_pa2"": null,
                  ""7661_pa2"": null,
                  ""7758_pa2"": null,
                  ""7697_pa1"": null,
                  ""problem_area_1"": null,
                  ""problem_area_2"": null,
                  ""spam"": null,
                  ""salesforce_problem_area_1"": null,
                  ""salesforce_problem_area_2"": null,
                  ""brand_id"": null
                },
                ""_links"": {
                  ""self"": {
                    ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/cases\/1"",
                    ""class"": ""case""
                  },
                  ""message"": {
                    ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/cases\/1\/message"",
                    ""class"": ""email""
                  },
                  ""customer"": {
                    ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/customers\/287193532"",
                    ""class"": ""customer""
                  },
                  ""labels"": {
                    ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/cases\/1\/labels"",
                    ""class"": ""label""
                  },
                  ""assigned_user"": {
                    ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/users\/22787152"",
                    ""class"": ""user""
                  },
                  ""assigned_group"": {
                    ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/groups\/474802"",
                    ""class"": ""group""
                  },
                  ""locked_by"": null,
                  ""history"": {
                    ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/cases\/1\/history"",
                    ""class"": ""history""
                  },
                  ""case_links"": {
                    ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/cases\/1\/links"",
                    ""class"": ""case_link"",
                    ""count"": 0
                  },
                  ""macro_preview"": {
                    ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/cases\/1\/macros\/preview"",
                    ""class"": ""macro_preview""
                  },
                  ""replies"": {
                    ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/cases\/1\/replies"",
                    ""class"": ""reply"",
                    ""count"": 1
                  },
                  ""draft"": {
                    ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/cases\/1\/replies\/draft"",
                    ""class"": ""reply""
                  },
                  ""notes"": {
                    ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/cases\/1\/notes"",
                    ""class"": ""note"",
                    ""count"": 0
                  },
                  ""attachments"": {
                    ""href"": ""\/api\/v2\/cases\/1\/attachments"",
                    ""class"": ""attachment"",
                    ""count"": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }";
        var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(str);
        Console.WriteLine(deserializeObject.total_entries);
    }
}


public class Rootobject
{
    public int total_entries { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public _Links _links { get; set; }
    public _Embedded _embedded { get; set; }
}

public class _Links
{
    public Self self { get; set; }
    public First first { get; set; }
    public Last last { get; set; }
    public object previous { get; set; }
    public Next next { get; set; }
}

public class Self
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
}

public class First
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
}

public class Last
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
}

public class Next
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
}

public class _Embedded
{
    public Entry[] entries { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public object external_id { get; set; }
    public string blurb { get; set; }
    public int priority { get; set; }
    public object locked_until { get; set; }
    public object[] label_ids { get; set; }
    public string active_at { get; set; }
    public string changed_at { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public string first_opened_at { get; set; }
    public string opened_at { get; set; }
    public string first_resolved_at { get; set; }
    public string resolved_at { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int active_notes_count { get; set; }
    public int active_attachments_count { get; set; }
    public bool has_pending_interactions { get; set; }
    public bool has_failed_interactions { get; set; }
    public object description { get; set; }
    public object language { get; set; }
    public string received_at { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public object[] labels { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public string route_status { get; set; }
    public Custom_Fields custom_fields { get; set; }
    public _Links1 _links { get; set; }
}

public class Custom_Fields
{
    public object exclude_portal { get; set; }
    public object exclude_notifications { get; set; }
    public object case_type { get; set; }
    public object product { get; set; }
    public object severity { get; set; }
    public object knowledge_status { get; set; }
    public object desk_case_id { get; set; }
    public object sla_status { get; set; }
    public object priority { get; set; }
    public object sla_violation { get; set; }
    public object sla_milestone_completed { get; set; }
    public object sync_to_salesforce { get; set; }
    public object _7616_pa2 { get; set; }
    public object _7643_pa1 { get; set; }
    public object _7714_pa1 { get; set; }
    public object _7616_pa1 { get; set; }
    public object _7643_pa2 { get; set; }
    public object _7714_pa2 { get; set; }
    public object entitlement_name { get; set; }
    public object escalation_level { get; set; }
    public object testing { get; set; }
    public object defect_number { get; set; }
    public object channel { get; set; }
    public object product_version { get; set; }
    public object exclude_from_reporting { get; set; }
    public object cw_id { get; set; }
    public object desk_agent_id { get; set; }
    public object desk_agent_name { get; set; }
    public object solution_codes { get; set; }
    public object _7723_pa2 { get; set; }
    public object _7670_pa2 { get; set; }
    public object _7661_pa1 { get; set; }
    public object _7634_pa2 { get; set; }
    public object _7670_pa1 { get; set; }
    public object _7758_pa1 { get; set; }
    public object _7634_pa1 { get; set; }
    public object _7688_pa1 { get; set; }
    public object _7723_pa1 { get; set; }
    public object _7688_pa2 { get; set; }
    public object _7661_pa2 { get; set; }
    public object _7758_pa2 { get; set; }
    public object _7697_pa1 { get; set; }
    public object problem_area_1 { get; set; }
    public object problem_area_2 { get; set; }
    public object spam { get; set; }
    public object salesforce_problem_area_1 { get; set; }
    public object salesforce_problem_area_2 { get; set; }
    public object brand_id { get; set; }
}

public class _Links1
{
    public Self1 self { get; set; }
    public Message message { get; set; }
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
    public Labels labels { get; set; }
    public Assigned_User assigned_user { get; set; }
    public Assigned_Group assigned_group { get; set; }
    public object locked_by { get; set; }
    public History history { get; set; }
    public Case_Links case_links { get; set; }
    public Macro_Preview macro_preview { get; set; }
    public Replies replies { get; set; }
    public Draft draft { get; set; }
    public Notes notes { get; set; }
    public Attachments attachments { get; set; }
}

public class Self1
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
}

public class Labels
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
}

public class Assigned_User
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
}

public class Assigned_Group
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
}

public class History
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
}

public class Case_Links
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}

public class Macro_Preview
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
}

public class Replies
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}

public class Draft
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
}

public class Notes
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}

public class Attachments
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string _class { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}
```